# Image Download in PHP

Tags: php

```
    $image_name = rawurldecode($name);
    $image_path = 'http://' . rawurldecode($path) . '/resources/images/banner/' . $image_name;
    $mime = explode('.', $image_name);

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Type: image/' . $mime[1]);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$image_name");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($image_path);
```

I have this code above it's running fine in my local but when I upload it in my server I can still download it but the image is broken. you can see the upper part of the image but the lower part is all gray.

Comment: Do you get an error? Are you allowed to load external URLs in your PHP installation? Are you sure the server address exists? Have you looked at the pictures file data to see if there's anything useful in there? It sounds like it's not loading the picture completely - might be size, might be your buffer being flushed too fast. Might be your content-length that's incorrect.

Comment: Why are you setting the content-type three times? Why aren't you setting it to an image content type in any of those times?

Comment: @Quentin The last `content-type` call is `header('Content-Type: image/' . $mime[1]);` (which, to be fair, is still wrong. `image/jpg` is incorrect - OP can't simply take the extension and assume it's a valid mime type. That's even being nice and expecting the URL to always include an extension). `image.txt.png` would also fail and output the mimetype `image/txt`.

Comment: thanks @h2ooooooo the problem is with the size and flush

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
$image_name = rawurldecode($name);
$image_path = 'http://' . rawurldecode($path) . '/resources/images/banner/' . $image_name;
$mime = explode('.', $image_name);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($image_path));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image_path));
readfile($image_name);
exit;
```